# Gatsby GDPR cookies plugin not working - Google analytics script is missing in <head> section

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I spent a lot of time troubleshooting my problem. I want to check value of my own cookie using `gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies`. I hardcoded, that value of `gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics` is always true to demonstrate if plugin is working correctly. Problem is, that my website still doesn't have `<script>` for Google analytics in `<head>` section. Any Ideas how to solve this? I tried to move plugin on different levels in `gatsby-config.js`, but nothing worked.
This is my configuration:

```
plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies`,
      options: {
        googleAnalytics: {
          trackingId: 'MY_TRACKING_ID',
          cookieName: 'gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics',
          anonymize: true,
          allowAdFeatures: false
        }
      },
      environments: ['production', 'development']
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Google recently applied some changes in their analytics API (migrated to `v4`) and it seems that some of the plugins haven't updated yet so they won't work. You will notice because the `trackingId` changed its format.

You can follow the stack trace in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/andrezimpel/gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies/issues/31) (from the plugin's owner).

At this point, you can make some trials:

- Upgrade the dependency keeping in mind that it may won't work yet: `npm upgrade gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies` or `yarn upgrade gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies`
- Switching to the old analytics tracking: set it in your Analytics dashboard, get the new tracking identifier and use it in:

  ```
  trackingId: 'OLD_TRACKING_ID',
  ```
- Swtich to another React-based approach using some other dependencies that supports the `v4` tracking, such [`ga-4-react`](https://github.com/unrealmanu/ga-4-react). You'll need to customize your `<head>` tag using `<Helmet>` component to add the tracking identifier. To avoid multiple instances of the same module, you may need to use some of the `gatsby-browsers.js` API, [`onClientEntry`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#onClientEntry) or [`onInitialClientRender`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#onInitialClientRender) should fit for your use-case:

  ```
  exports.onClientEntry = () => {
     yourAnalyticsFunction()
  }
  ```